# Cookie always return null in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

net web pages,in the first one, I wrote like below:

```
protected void lbXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("RequestedXML");
    cookie["xmlContent"] = hide_XML.Value;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('XML_Editor.aspx', '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, resizable=yes, width=800px, height=500px', true);</script>");
}
```

In XML_Editor.aspx, I wrote code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page lastPage = (Page)Context.Handler;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["RequestedXML"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = cookie["xmlContent"];
        }

    }
}
```

the problem is that the cookie always return null to me in Page_Load in XML_Editor.aspx, why is that?

Comment: Are you testing this locally or from a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be you code, try it:

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("RequestedXML");
            cookie.Value =hide_XML.Value;

            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Write("<script>window.open('XML_Editor.aspx', '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, resizable=yes, width=800px, height=500px', true);</script>");
```

XML_Editor.aspx

```
Page lastPage = (Page)Context.Handler;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                var cookie = Request.Cookies["RequestedXML"];
                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(cookie.Value);
                }

            }
```

Comment: No, I mean Request.Cookies["RequestedXML"]; always return null, I don't know why.